# IE6 caching cookie values when back button is used

Tags: php

Our user authentication system makes use of cookies and $_SESSION variables to determine logged-in status. Every page tests for the presence of a user_id $_SESSION variable and a user_auth cookie:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) || !isset($_COOKIE['user_auth'])){
     // send user through login
}
```

and sends the user through the login process if they're not found.The logout button loads the following page:

```
<?php 

session_start();
setcookie('user_auth','',time()-360000,'/','domain.com');
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location: http://home.domain.com");

?>
```

In Firefox, logging out and then pressing the back button sends the user back through the login process.  However, in IE6 these values are retained and the user is able to access the page again.  The values are definitely being destroyed as reloading the page sends the user back through the login process, but I'd obviously prefer IE6 to send the user straight back to login as Firefox does.  I have tried using no-cache and revalidate headers, to no avail.

(Before it's suggested, using Firefox/Safari/Chrome/IE8 is not an available option.)

Comment: as I've said, not an option.  IE6 is the corporate SOE browser, at least for six more months.

Comment: I would assume the session_destroy() would destroy the session from the server, thus if a client clicked back and the request was posted again the server would say "hang on, that session doesn't exist any more" and return an error (or you could redirect to a login page).

Comment: The error you are reporting is that the server will actually log the user back in...is that correct?

Comment: No, it's just displaying the previous page as though the user is logged in. If the page is reloaded though, it does correctly force a login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not caching the cookie values, it's caching the pages themselves. If you want that not to happen, you could disable the cache by using headers.

Depending on your content, you might also want to have the usual "please clear the cache and close the window" thing on your log-out message page.

Comment: I ended up closing the window for IE6 logouts - not ideal, but will work until we transition to IE8/9 in four months.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also test the agent type in an if / else set, and run different actions on logout based on the browser type. Like IE 6 I think you could unset the session and exit() the processing completely: unset($_SESSION['variable']);  ..

I believe this is also a header control you can run in IE6 like **Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"**.. Not sure if this at all helps or answers your questions, but there certainly is some way to control this. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Content with "Content-Encoding: gzip" Is Always Cached Although You Use "Cache-Control: no-cache"

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321722

You could also try disabling gzip.